Will Windows 11 install the Windows 11 24H2 update automatically?
Pro and Home versions of Windows 11 will automatically download and install updates from Microsoft.  Users can opt to delay MS updates for a short period of time, but not indefinitely.
Does Microsoft's forced-update policy also apply to the Windows 11 24H2 update?
Specifically, how long will the Windows 11 24H2 update stick around as an available update in Windows Update on a Windows 11 box before it is force-installed?

If you use the group policy to remain on 23H2 you can wait more than a year. If you don’t you are automatically upgraded anywhere after the period where support for 23H2 is dropped. Now with professional you likely would remain on 23h2 past that year but eventually all security updates eventually would stop.

Please research the subject then revise [edit] your question based on that research
